# Filter rows that match string within the "current" and "next" rows

Tags: r

I have read a continuous text file as a dataframe (df) in R with `readr:: read_tsv ("file.txt", show_col_types = F)`. The resulting df has 1 column and 80,398 rows. I want to filter and keep the rows that contain `"Run = \\d{1,3}"`, but only if it's followed by `".*Final Intermolecular Energy     ="` after another 8 rows.

Could anyone shed me some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `filter()` using two criteria, one for "Run = \\d{1,3}" and the other for "Final Intermolecular ..." using the [`lead()` function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html) from the dplyr package to ensure the "Final Intermolecular ..." is 8 rows ahead of the "Run = \\d{1,3}", e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x = c(0, "Run = 123", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, "xxyyzz Final Intermolecular Energy     = 123", 0,
                       0, "Run = 345", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, "not final energy", 0))
df
#>                                               x
#> 1                                             0
#> 2                                     Run = 123
#> 3                                             1
#> 4                                             2
#> 5                                             3
#> 6                                             4
#> 7                                             5
#> 8                                             6
#> 9                                             7
#> 10                                            8
#> 11 xxyyzz Final Intermolecular Energy     = 123
#> 12                                            0
#> 13                                            0
#> 14                                    Run = 345
#> 15                                            1
#> 16                                            2
#> 17                                            3
#> 18                                            4
#> 19                                            5
#> 20                                            6
#> 21                                            7
#> 22                                            8
#> 23                             not final energy
#> 24                                            0

df %>%
  filter(str_detect(x, "Run = \\d{1,3}") & 
           str_detect(lead(x, n = 9), ".*Final Intermolecular Energy     ="))
#>           x
#> 1 Run = 123

# doesn't detect "Run = 345" as it doesn't match the second criteria
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>